# Добавление и удаление класса при нажатии на элемент

Tags: javascript

У меня есть элемент `label`, мне надо что бы при нажатии на него, к нему добавлялся класс `check`. При повторном нажатии на элемент необходимо удалить данный класс.

Мне надо написать код на чистом JS.

Вот что я пытался сделать, но ничего не работает.

```
var checked = document.querySelector('#add_check');

checked.onclick = function(){
    this.classList.add('check')
};
checked.onclick = function(){
    this.classList.remove('check')
};
```

Второй вариант:

```
var checked = document.querySelector('#add_check');

checked.onclick = function(){
    this.classList.add('check')

    if(this.classList.contains('check')){
        this.classList.remove('check')
    }
};
```

`

Comment: В первом вешаете сразу два обработчика добавить и удалить класс. Во втором варианте вы добавляете класс, потом сразу проверяете есть ли он и удаляете. Тоесть он вседа будет удален.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Свойство объекта может иметь только одно значение. Вторым присваиванием вы перетираете предыдущее.
2. Вам нужно определиться, использовать toggle или ручную логику. В совокупности они друг другу мешают

```js
document.querySelector('.label')
  .onclick = function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('checked')) {
  this.classList.remove('checked')
  } else {this.classList.add('checked')}
}
```

```css
.label {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.label.checked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class=label>Label</div>
```

Если необходимо навешивать более одного обработчика, да и вообще для единства стиля, лучше использовать "слушатели событий" - event listeners

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.label').forEach(label =>
  label.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('checked');
  }))
```

```css
.label {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.label.checked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class=label>Label</div>
<div class="label checked">Label</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, заработало как часы, я понял Вашу логику)))))) Выручили))) Обязательно выберу Ваш ответ верным)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var checked = document.querySelector('#add_check');
checked.onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle('check');
    console.log(checked)
};
```

```html
<div id="add_check">add_check</div>
```